# How can I do simple math operands with letters in c++?

Tags: c++, math

I need to do some basic maths operands with equations that includes both numbers and letters.

For example I have `7A + 3A = 20BC`, then I want to get that `B = 10A/20C = 1A/2C`.

However as far as I know doing arithmetic operands with letters is not supported by C++ so the compiler will be pissed of as soon as I'm trying to put letters (chars) in a int or double memory. I am thinking that maybe you could get the letters ascii number and in some way "connect" that ascii number to the integer number that comes before or after that letter but I haven't been able to come up with a code example of that since, well I do not know how.

I have no idea how to proceed with this so if anyone know how I can apply arithmetic with letters (maybe write my own method or class for this?) I would really appreciate your answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me just say that writing a program to solve equations using symbolic logic is **not** trivial

Comment: You need to reimplement kind of Mathematica or sympy in C++. Quite a huge task, especially if you are a beginner. Change language instead!

Comment: You might want to look into context-free grammars and parsing. However what you're doing is still more complex than just grammars.

Comment: @n.m. No it is not a homework. I have four planes in space that is building a tetrahedron, and I'm gonna calculate the length of a vector that goes from one corner of the tetrahedron to where it crosses the opposite plane. I am trying to learn C++ and I figured applying a math question like this into  C++ code could be a good learning practice for me, but it might just be to complicated for a beginner like me.

Comment: Don't try to write a program to solve arbitrary algebra problems. Solve *your particular* algebra problem, then write a program that runs numbers through that algebra, as and when you need it to

Comment: C++ might be a too low-level language for this task. [MATLAB Symbolic Math](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html) is convenient for this (but is not free software); I am sure other languages (like Python) have libraries for that too ([example](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)).

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a good starting point for learning programming or C++.

Comment: @Jacob Equations are usually solved   by computers using various algorithms, and not by doing algebra as you would do in  school.  For example, a system of linear equations would be solved on computer using matrices and Gauss-Jordan elimination, not by moving symbols around like human beings in an algebra course.  Of course you can write a program to simulate the symbolic manipulation, but you are entering graduate, possibly PhD level type stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom algebra class and operator overloading,

```
class Algebra { 
    private: 
    int value;
    char variable; 
    public: 
        Algebra(int x, char y)  {value = x;   variable = y;} 
        void print() { cout << value << variable << endl; } 

    friend Algebra operator + (Algebra const &, Algebra const &); 
    }; 


Algebra operator + (Algebra const &c1, Algebra const &c2) 
{ 
     // Return NULL if c1.variable != c2.variable.
     return Algebra(c1.value + c2.value, c1.variable); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    Algebra c1(10, x), c2(2, x); 
    Algebra c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could model a *term*:

```
struct Term
{
  double coefficient;
  char   variable_name;
  double exponent;
};
```

The next step would be to *parse* the expression into terms.
Once you have a container of `Term`s, you can manipulate them anyway you want.

**Edit 1:**
You may also want to consider a `Fraction` class also.  This would allow you to have terms as numerators and denominators.

Another route is to model an *expression*:

```
class Expression
{
  Term a;
  Term b;
  std::string operation;
};
```

The expression would contain two `Terms` and the operation between them.
Also consider an expression tree to get the precedence correct.  Search the internet for "C++ Shunting Yard Algorithm".

Answer (score 2):

You need some support for **algebraic manipulation**, i.e. a [computer algebra system (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).

Wikipedia provides a [list of such systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). A free C++ library supporting algebraic manipulations is [GiNaC](https://ginac.de/). For example the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ginac/ginac.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace GiNaC;

int main()
{
    symbol a("a"), b("b"), x("x"), y("y");
    lst eqns, vars;
    eqns = a*x+b*y==3, x-y==b;
    vars = x, y;
    cout << " solving " << eqns << '\n'
         << " for     " << vars << '\n'
         << " gives:  " << lsolve(eqns, vars) << endl;
}
```

generates output

```
 solving {x*a+y*b==3,x-y==b}
 for     {x,y}
 gives:  {x==(a+b)^(-1)*(3+b^2),y==-(-3+a*b)*(a+b)^(-1)}
```